# JavaScript function needs to be reloaded for specific elements instead of the entire page in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following form in Django and every time a user selects the `Finalized` option, two fields should become non-editable and when the user selects the `Active` option then those two fields should become editable again. However, it seems that this works only once the page is first loaded, then I need to select to another option and then reload the entire page to make the JS code to work.

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load widget_tweaks %} 
{% block content %}

<body onload="makeReadOnly();">
  <div id="form-group">
    <form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="tweet-composer">
        <label>Insert your task</label>
          {{ form.task|add_class:"card js-keeper-editor" }}
      </div>
     <label>Select your category</label>
      {{ form.category|add_class:"card" }}
     <label>Current points:</label>
      {{ form.points|add_class:"card" }}
     {% endif %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

{% endblock content %}
<script type="text/javascript">
{% block jquery %}
  function makeReadOnly(){        
      if (document.getElementById('id_status').value == 'Finalized'){
          document.getElementById('id_task').readOnly=true;
          document.getElementById('id_category').readOnly=true;
     }else if (document.getElementById('id_status').value == 'Active'){ 
          document.getElementById('id_task').readOnly=true;
          document.getElementById('id_category').readOnly=false;
  }
{% endblock %}
</script>
```

[image]

How can I make the JS to load immediately after options are changed instead of changing one option and then reloading the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your function, add the following statement:

```
document.getElementById('id_status').addEventListener('change', makeReadOnly);
```

This will bind the `makeReadOnly` function to the change event of your dropdown, and will set the status of your other fields without having to reload.

This has to be outside the function, as such:

```
function makeReadOnly() {
  ...
}
document.getElementById('id_status').addEventListener('change', makeReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a body onload function, I would use a button onClick function.

onLoad will only run one time, however, onClick will trigger every time the related element is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem that you are running your function on load 
instead you should add a listener on whenever your selection change.

if you are using jQuery you can easily achieve this by using the `change()` function.

the code should be like this:

```
$(function() {
            $("#id_status").change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "finalized") {
                    $("#id_category").prop("disabled", true);
                    $("#id_task").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else{
                    $("#id_category").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#id_task").prop("disabled", false);
            });
        });
```